# will libnids hash algorithm get a conflict?

Tags: algorithm, hash, hashmap, libnids

```
u_int
mkhash (u_int src, u_short sport, u_int dest, u_short dport)
{
  u_int res = 0;
  int i;
  u_char data[12];
  u_int *stupid_strict_aliasing_warnings=(u_int*)data;
  *stupid_strict_aliasing_warnings = src;
  *(u_int *) (data + 4) = dest;
  *(u_short *) (data + 8) = sport;
  *(u_short *) (data + 10) = dport;
  for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    res = ( (res << 8) + (data[perm[i]] ^ xor[i])) % 0xff100f;
  return res;
}
```

Here is libnids hash algorithm above. When table size is 65536 ,Can two different tuple4 get the same hash value ?

Comment: The input size is bigger than the hash value, so yes, by the [pidgeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) your hash function can not be injective

Answer (score 3):

You have 96 bits that you're trying to hash into 32 bits, so the probability of collision occurring at some point is 100%.

Assuming that your hash function generates uniformly distributed values, the chance of collision when generating 65,536 32-bit hash values is pretty close to 50%.

I discussed this at some length in my article [Birthdays, Random Numbers, and Hash Keys](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=792). It includes reference to a simple formula that can estimate the likelihood of collision given a key size and number of hashes generated.